# Is using triggers a good practice for updating count or timestamp fields?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, eventtrigger

I have two tables (simplified):

```
TABLE batch
batch_id      uuid
student_count smallint

TABLE students
batch_id    uuid
student_id  uuid
```

So I want to update student_count(add 1) whenever a student is inserted into the database. My question is should I use a trigger to update the student_count or use a separate query to update student_count. (My database and server are not on same machine.)

I cannot use a before trigger since insertion may fail.(unless I use a transaction which I want to avoid if I am using triggers.)

so basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239721/update-timestamp-on-related-referenced-row-on-update-or-insert?rq=1) is a good practice ?

Comment: Might be better asked on sister site, DBA.StackExchange.com

Comment: There are a couple misconceptions in the sentence beginning "I cannot use ..." DML triggers (all 4 types) run within the execution sequence of the particular DML. This means that if the action fails (insertion in this case) any action taken in a BEFORE trigger is also 'erased'. So you can use a before trigger. Secondly, **ALL** postgres DML runs within a transaction. If you don't start a transaction specifically the statement itself effectively initiates one (it will be automatically committed), but it's a transaction none the less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tasks like that it is best to use a trigger, precisely because the trigger is guaranteed to run, and it automatically runs in the same transaction as the triggering statement. That is a good thing, because it means that either both operations will succeed or both will fail (atomicity), which is precisely what you want in such a case.

The best solution, however, might be not to store the redundant `student_count` at all, but to calculate it on the fly when you `SELECT` from the tables. Persisting redundant data is only a good solution if calculating it when you need it would be intolerable from a performance perspective.

Comment: The question above is one use case, the important one is an events table which is 50x larger and also the most queried table of db (almost all queries pass though it). So I want to reduce the load by keeping latesr event on an entity with the entity table itself rather than making a Max query everytime. Do you still think the Max query will be best solution ? (Keeping the most queried and 50x ratio in mind)

Comment: That is hard to answer in general. You would have to measure the times and see if it is acceptable or not. It is definitely OK to introduce redundancies like that if it saves the day performance-wise, I just wouldn't do it if it is not necessary.